# Parameters for dlib::find_min_bobyqa

Tags: dlib

I'm working on the C++ version of Matt Zucker's [Page dewarping](https://mzucker.github.io/2016/08/15/page-dewarping.html). So far everything works fine, but I have a problem with optimization. In line 748 of  [Github repo](https://github.com/mzucker/page_dewarp/blob/master/page_dewarp.py) Matt uses [optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) function from Scipy. My C++ equivalent is [find_min_bobyqa](http://dlib.net/dlib/optimization/optimization_bobyqa_abstract.h.html#find_min_bobyqa) from dlib.net. The code is:

```
auto f = [&](const column_vector& ppts) { return objective( dstpoints, ppts, keypoint_index); };
dlib::find_min_bobyqa(f,
               params,
               2 * params.nr() + 1,    // npt - number of interpolation points: x.size() + 2 <= npt && npt <= (x.size()+1)*(x.size()+2)/2
               dlib::uniform_matrix<double>(params.nr(), 1, -2),  // lower bound constraint
               dlib::uniform_matrix<double>(params.nr(), 1, 2),   // upper bound constraint
               1,    // initial trust region radius
               1e-5,  // stopping trust region radius
               4000    // max number of objective function evaluations
);
```

In my concrete example `params` is a `dlib::column_vector` with double values and length = 189. Every element of params is less than 2.0 and greater than -2.0. Function `objective()` returns double value and "alone" it works properly because I get the same value as in the Python version. But after running `fin_min_bobyqa` function  I usually get the message:

> Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'dlib:bobyqa_failure', return from BOBYQA because the objective function has been called max_f_evals times.

I set `max_f_evals` to quite big value to see if it optimizes at all, but it doesn't.  I did some tweaking with parameters but without good results. How should I set the parameters of `find_min_bobyqa` to get the right solution?

Answer (score 1):

I am very interested in this issue as well. Zucker's work, with very minor tweaks, is ideal for straightening sheet music images, and I was looking for ways to implement it in a mobile platform when I came across your question.

My research so far suggests that BOBYQA is not the equivalent of Powell's method in scipy. BOBYQA is constrained, and the one in scipy is not.

See these links for more information, and a possible way to compile the right supporting library - I would try UOBYQA or NEWUOA.

https://github.com/jacobwilliams/PowellOpt
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#rdd2e1855725e-3
(See the Notes section)
EDIT: see C version here:
https://github.com/emmt/Algorithms/tree/master/newuoa

I wanted to post this as a comment, but I don't have enough points for that.

I am very interested in your progress. If you're willing, please keep me posted.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this problem. I used [PRAXIS](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/praxis/praxis.html) library, because it doesn't need derivative information and is fast.
I modified the code a little to my needs and now it is faster around few  seconds than original version written in Python.

Comment: I managed to get a working version for iOS, using a clunky combination of Swift and C++. I did use NEWUOA, and it works fine on mobile devices, provided I limit the number of parameters. Did you happen to compare NEWUOA to Praxis?

Comment: Congratulations. I didn't have time to compare both methods, because another task was waiting for me. Maybe in the future, but I can't promise that.